# Why is file size returning to be 0 when it shouldn't be?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, file-io

I have a function which reads a through a bunch of files and stores the file's size and name in a class called Partition. This is the line where it happens:

```
new_PI = Partition(os.stat(partition_name).st_size, partition_name)
```

For some reason, I noticed that there was a problem with the file sizes being stored in the Partition class. To check what was being stored, I added a printing below my code:

```
print(os.stat(partition_name).st_size)
```

and it printed zero for each file. When I try it in the shell, it works fine (returning 1640). Has anyone encountered something similar?

Comment: what is an example value of `partition_name`? If it's a filename without an absolute path, is the current directory what you think it is?

Comment: it's just a filename like 'output_0.txt'. How can I check if it's in the right directory?

Comment: A tested reproducer (that is, since this only happens during scripted invocation, something you've copied-and-pasted into a script and validated reproduces the problem when that script is run without any other contents within the same script being necessary) would be appropriate here.

Comment: Sorry not too familiar with things here. What is a tested reproducer?

Comment: Can you create a short standalone script which exhibits this behavior out of the box on a different computer? See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: As I was trying to make a tested reproduced, I found my error! I wasn't closing the files in the right spot after working with them.

Comment: Great! You might consider either adding what you found as an answer for your own question, or closing/deleting it. (As a new user, you don't want too many of your questions closed or deleted, but just a few shouldn't matter).